# Where to put code required by the layout in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

When rendering a view from a controller a standard practice is to put your code in the controller, and then pass the necessary variables to the view, so they can be used when rendering.

This view usually extends a layout view.

Where do I put my code that is necessary in the layout view, and how do I inject it?

I looked at the login/register buttons from the official Laravel code as an example.
To render them properly, the information whether the user is currently  logged in or not, is required in the view.

In Laravel this looks like this:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
    <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
@else
    ...
```

So the view is actually getting the data on its own. Even if the code is contained in one function, this goes against my understanding of separation of code. In my understanding the necessary data should be passed to the view and not rely on any external methods. What if the method name changes etc.

Is there a better way to do it in laravel?

For example in Zend/Magento there is the concept of a "block". Where there is a class with code that corresponds to a view and can be used to supply data.

Would it make sense to put this in middle ware or a service provider?

Comment: To be honest, I think this is absolutely fine, but if you want to contain it within a variable, you'll want to place it in a view composer wherein you check whether the current user is a guest, and then share that view composer with all views the logic applies to. Here's documentation for L5.2: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers (Edit: please note that how view composers are shared has changed slightly in the past, so make sure you look at the documentation for the version you're using.)

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for @JoelHinz If you move taht to an answer, ill mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I think this is absolutely fine, but if you want to contain it within a variable, you'll want to place it in a view composer wherein you check whether the current user is a guest, and then share that view composer with all views the logic applies to.

Here's documentation for L5.2: http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers

Please note that how view composers are shared has changed slightly in the past, so make sure you look at the documentation for the version you're using.